# Paginación en Express con Mongoose

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, async

me podrian ayudar a resolver mi función `get` de forma asíncrona la tengo con promesas de la siguiente manera y funciona bien pero de la forma await que es la segunda no puedo realizarla

```
router.get("", (req, res, next) => {
    const paginaSize = +req.query.pagesize;
    const paginaActual = +req.query.page;
    const perfilQuery = Perfil.find();
    if(paginaSize && paginaActual) {
        perfilQuery
        .skip(paginaSize * (paginaActual - 1))
        .limit(paginaSize)
    }
    perfilQuery.then(documentos => {
    res.status(200).json({
     posts: documentos
    });
   });
});
```

y de la forma **async/await**

```
router.get('', async (req, res) => {
    const paginaSize = +req.query.pagesize;
    const paginaActual = +req.query.page;
    const perfilQuery = Perfil.find();
    try {
        if(paginaSize && paginaActual) {
            perfilQuery
            .skip(paginaSize * (paginaActual - 1))
            .limit(paginaSize)
        }
        await perfilQuery
        res.status(200).json({
            mensaje: "todos los perfiles",
            perfil: perfiles
        })
    } catch (e) { res.status(500).send() }
})
```

pero al realizar la petición obtengo un estatus con `error` **500**, cual podría ser mi problema. Les agradecería el que me pudieran ayudar.

Comment: Hola Gerdado, en el código `router.get("",....)` no añades ninguna ruta, como por ejemplo, `router.get("/lista",....)`. Es posible que sea eso?. También, porque haces `+req.query.pagesize` o `+req.query.pag` con un + delante?

Comment: @planta4, lo del símbolo `+` delante del nombre de las variables es para cambiar el tipo de las mismas, se le conoce como [Operador Unario Más](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Aritméticos#Unario_más_()). Por defecto el tipo de variables que leemos del objeto `query` en un `response` de `Node/Express` es `String`. Es por ello que el OP usa el operador unario para intentar convertir la misma en un tipo `Number`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras, gracias por la aclaración, nunca lo había visto. Lo tendré en cuenta. Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que no estás ejecutando realmente tu consulta cuando usas `async/await`.

Tienes lo siguiente:

```
await perfilQuery;
```

Sin embargo, `perfilQuery` no es una función o un método ejecutable por sí solo. Es un objeto [`Query`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html):

> Los modelos de Mongoose proveen varias funciones *helper* estáticas para operaciones CRUD. Cada una de estas funciones devuelve un Objeto [Query](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Query) de Mongoose.

Por lo tanto, cuando asignas:

```
const perfilQuery = Perfil.find();
```

Estás asignando un Objeto Query a la variable `perfilQuery`.

Los objetos [`Query` no son Promesas](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises), sin embargo poseen un método `.then()` para usarlos como si se tratase de una Promesa.

Dado que deseas implementar un llamado asíncrono usando `async/await` debes hacer uso de otro método que poseen los objetos `Query`.

El método [`.exec()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-exec) ejecuta la consulta y devuelve una Promesa.

Según la documentación de Mongoose, éste método recibe como parámetros un `String` o una `Función Callback`.

El `String` representa el método a aplicar: `'find'`, `'update'`, etc. Sin embargo, dado que el Objeto `Query` fue instanciado usando la función estática `find()`, no es necesario pasar como parámetro ningún valor:

```
await perfilQuery.exec();
```

Y como dicha consulta debe devolver una lista con los perfiles encontrados en la colección, debemos asignar el resultado de la misma a una variable:

```
const perfiles = await perfilQuery.exec();
```

Ya sabemos entonces la razón del problema, pero no lo habías encontrado, porque no estabas depurando el error.

Llamar directamente al objeto `perfilQuery` como lo estabas haciendo usando `await` no causaba el error. El error se originaba al intentar enviar una variable no definida:

```
res.status(200).json({
  mensaje: "todos los perfiles",
  perfil: perfiles // <- perfiles no ha sido definido
});
```

Es una buena práctica en desarrollo, mostrar los mensajes de error por consola:

```
catch(e) {
  console.log(e.message);
  ...
}
```

De esa forma hubieras advertido el problema y tal vez hubieses hallado la solución por ti mismo.

El código completo debería verse parecido al siguiente:

```
router.get('', async (req, res) => {
  const paginaSize = +req.query.pagesize;
  const paginaActual = +req.query.page;
  const perfilQuery = Perfil.find();
  if(paginaSize && paginaActual) {
    perfilQuery
    .skip(paginaSize * (paginaActual - 1))
    .limit(paginaSize)
  }
  try {
    const perfiles = await perfilQuery.exec();
    res.status(200).json({
      mensaje: "todos los perfiles",
      perfil: perfiles
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
    res.status(500).send();
  }
});
```

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas y te ayude a resolver el problema.